# How to write multiple files in SQL, from a query result?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a data set of a 1m+ records. 
I need to output the query to multiple files depending on a order by .

Example Data set:

```
ID        StoreName      StoreChain   MoreData........
 1        walmart NY     Walmart      ...
 2        Walmarty NJ    Walmart      ....
 3        Target NY      Target       ....
 4        Costco NY      Costco       ....
```

Example Query

```
 Select StoreName, SotreChain,moreData order by StoreName
```

I need to write for each store name. (4 files)

```
Select StoreName, StoreChain,moreData order by StoreChain
```

I need to write a file for each Chain, (3 files)

Today I use a CLR SP, it works fine but is a little slow (1h for 1000 files of 200-400 lines each)

I want to know if there is a pure T-SQL solution, if needed it can use the command shell.

and it has to write to a log table every time it creates a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the best solution here would be to use a SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) package.  You can design this using Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS).

Using this, you can specify your T-SQL as the source and flat files as the destination of your queries.

You can even go as far to schedule the SSIS package to run routinely.

Comment: This can work, but the tables are created, consumed and destroy and there is a second table that determines witch columns dose the file contains. I know did´t specify this in the question so I´ll accept your response by the end of the day.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Shark. You should try doing this using SSIS packages. Here are links to a couple of tutorials:

- [Creating a Simple SSIS Package](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/207/creating-a-simple-ssis-package/)
- [Video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPdUYpi-m10)

When you figure out how to use the tool you will be able to set up ssis package to import data from huge table to another in less than a minute. I definitely recommend this option if you plan to deal with large amount of data